# How to use a loop to change a variable

Tags: r, bioinformatics, biomart

Is there any way to use a loop to write this code? Each line of code is identical except from the species name

```
ensembl_hsapiens <- useMart("ensembl", 
                        dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
ensembl_mouse <- useMart("ensembl", 
                     dataset = "mmusculus_gene_ensembl")
ensembl_chicken <- useMart("ensembl",
                       dataset = "ggallus_gene_ensembl")
```

Comment: `lapply(setNames(, c("hsapiens", "mmusculus", "ggallus")), function(x) useMart("ensembl", dataset = sprintf("%s_gene_ensembl", x)))` maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach. Note that using a loop (or a loop-equivalent construct) to populate the global environment isn't often a good idea. But it's what you asked for.

There's nothing special about `useMart`, so I'll make up a nonsense function that takes two character arguments:

```
foo <- function(x, y) {
  nchar(paste(x, y))
}
```

Here are the species names. I'll use them for the object names as well.

```
species <- c("hsapiens", "mmusculus", "ggallus")
```

Now, you want to create three named objects in the global environment. You can use the `assign` function for this, noting that you use `pos=2` because each loop of `lapply` is done in its own environment.

```
lapply(species, function(s) assign(paste0("ensembl_", s),
                                   foo("ensemble", paste0(s, "_gene_ensembl")),
                                   pos = 1))
```

This gives you what you want. You can replace `foo` use `useMart`.

Now, is this a good idea? Perhaps not. I would be more inclined to keep the objects themselves in a list.

```
objs <- lapply(species, function(s) foo("ensemble", paste0(s, "_gene_ensembl")))
names(objs) <- paste0("ensemble_", species)
```

You can access them using statements like `objs$ensemble_hsapiens` or `objs[["ensemble_hsapiens"]]`